# My src in Java Resources suddenly disappear

Tags: java, eclipse, project-structure

I'm creating a Dynamic Web Project, and I have src in my Java Resources then suddenly src disappear inside of it. I find out that the src became a context folder in the root along with Java Resources, Build, WEB-INF and WebContent folders. Why did this happen?

[image: This is the src]

Comment: Plz share the images to clear understanding about your problem.

Comment: i edited my post now with image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify your java build path of the project and check if `src` is present there.
Right click on the project and select Build Path -> Configure Build Path.If `src` is not in build path it won't show you can add src folder in your build path of the project by following below steps,

- right click on project
- select properties
- select java build path
- goto source tab
- click add folder
- select your source folder (src/main/java)

Also look at  perspective is will be in Navigator perspective.

Answer (score 1):

In your IDE goto Windows-> Show View -> Navigator, check the image for the same try to change it to "navigator" view your will be able to see it. If not please share the images of it, then we will help you more[image]

Comment: My perspective is in Java EE. I edited it with image now. thanks

Comment: Go to navigator view

Answer (score 1):

@msagala you have to `Configure build path`. Then under `Source` tab click `Add` button and you will see your existing source folder.
I hope this will help you.